# Delete key with its values in a multidimensional array in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I need to be able to remove a custom key from an array inserted into a WordPress options table, here is the array i get in return using print_r:

```
Array (
[customkeyone] => Array (
   [itemname] => 'name'
   [sortorder] => 1
   [date] => 1393042529
   [target] => 1
   )
[customkeytwo] => Array (
   [itemname] => 'nametwo'
   [sortorder] => 1
   [date] => 1393042525
   [target] => 1
   )
[customkeythree] => Array (
   [itemname] => 'namethree'
   [sortorder] => 1
   [date] => 1393042522
   [target] => 1
   )
)
```

I tried different methods and have come close but not able to actually remove/unset the entire custom key itself. Lets say I want to unset "customkeytwo", I would need a way to pass this custom id and remove it:

Handler example:

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {

    //ID in this case is "customkeytwo" 
    if ($_REQUEST['id'] != ''){

                $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $myoptions = get_option('myoptions'); 

                //some method to unset the custom key with $id

                //update with new results
                update_option('myoptions', $myoptions);
```

And this is how I want the result to be after I remove it:

```
Array (
[customkeyone] => Array (
   [itemname] => 'name'
   [sortorder] => 1
   [date] => 1393042529
   [target] => 1
   )
[customkeythree] => Array (
   [itemname] => 'namethree'
   [sortorder] => 1
   [date] => 1393042522
   [target] => 1
   ) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `unset` ?

```
unset($myoptions[$_REQUEST['id']]); // will remove "customkeytwo"
print_r($myoptions);
```

Comment: have you debug it ? What gives you `var_dump($options)` & `var_dump($_REQUEST['id'])` ?

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST['id'])  ---->  string(12) "customkeytwo"

Comment: i'm able to remove key values, but not the key itself

Comment: Sorry, this is actually correct, after having some good rest I was able to see the small mistake on my side with the update option line, but it is now working and this method is correct

Comment: Can you share your "small mistake" and what you did to fix it?  I have the same issue and I have tried to unset the array and then resubmit it with update_option but I get an empty entry for the option when I do that